# mysql overlaps of two tables in timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, timestamp

I have two tables in MySQL. In each of these tables, devices with their MAC-Addresses and information of their states area saved.

These states do start and end at certain timestamps (startTime,endTime) and their durations (endTime-startTime), and are caused by certain id's.

Now i want to find the overlappings between the certain events "move" and "load" separated by days, like this:

```
sum of time, when movement took place (value in the fiddle: 421)
sum of time, when load took place (value in the fiddle: 520)
sum of time, when movement and load took place (value in the fiddle: 391)
```

The result of the query should look like this:

```
ID                  DATE                            ALL_MOVEMENT    ALL_LOAD    LOAD_MOVEMENT
00:50:c2:63:10:1a   October, 29 2012 00:00:00+0000  421             520         391
00:50:c2:63:10:1a   February, 22 2013 00:00:00+0000 421             520         391
00:50:c2:63:10:1b   February, 22 2013 00:00:00+0000 181             220         181
```

I have prepared a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c210c

Update: A fiddle which offers the things i want in a different table structure can be seen here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31b94/1

Comment: have updated the question and the fiddle!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand how the data set correlates with the result set but it seems to me you want something more or less like this...

```
 SELECT m.id
      , DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(m.starttime))Date,SUM(m.duration) all_movement
      , SUM(l.duration) all_load
   FROM move_table m
   JOIN load_table l
     ON l.id = m.id
    AND l.endtime > m.starttime
    AND l.starttime < m.endtime
  GROUP 
     BY m.id
      , DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(m.starttime));
 +-------------------+------------+--------------+----------+
 | id                | Date       | all_movement | all_load |
 +-------------------+------------+--------------+----------+
 | 00:50:c2:63:10:1a | 2012-10-29 |          391 |      520 |
 | 00:50:c2:63:10:1a | 2013-02-22 |          391 |      520 |
 | 00:50:c2:63:10:1b | 2013-02-22 |          181 |      220 |
 +-------------------+------------+--------------+----------+
```

Incidentally, `duration` appears to be redundant in this context as (for instance) SUM(m.endtime-m.starttime) will get you the same result.

Comment: duration is there because it is more efficient for queries...it's a exchange of storage place and computation time.

Comment: This is quite a good start, but the intersection of movement and load time is left at the moment. I have posted another fiddle above, just have a look.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to resolve the difference between 'load' and 'no load' because there is no real information about it in the database - but maybe this is a starting point for you to play around with.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.D, SUM(a.MOVETIME) AS ALL_MOVEMENT, SUM(a.LOADTIME) AS ALL_LOAD
FROM (
SELECT ID, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(startTime)) AS d, SUM(duration) AS MOVETIME, 0 AS LOADTIME
FROM move_table
GROUP BY ID, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(startTime))
UNION
SELECT ID, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(startTime)) AS d, 0 AS MOVETIME, SUM(duration) AS LOADTIME
FROM load_table
GROUP BY ID, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(startTime))) AS a
GROUP BY a.ID, a.D
```

Comment: A nice start, but intersection of movement and load time is left at the moment. I have posted another fiddle above, just have a look.